# Differences between Oracle Cloud for Industry vs Oracle Public Cloud?

Tags: cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, private-cloud, public-cloud

What are the major differences between Oracle Cloud for Industry and Oracle Public Cloud? I would like to know in what sense does Oracle mean the cloud is public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle cloud for industry has multiple cloud solutions( with their product bundles) targeted to specific industries like financial services, Consumer goods etc. Their public cloud is just like any other public cloud which means the platform or infrastructure provided by the cloud will run in oracle's data centers and not on say a company's datacenter which would then become private cloud. In case of a public cloud anyone is eligible to buy computing services and use it. You are only ensured logical separation and not physical hardware level separation.

Answer (score 0):

OCI predates OPC. 
OCI is a SaaS offering from Oracle lines of businesses such as Retail, Health Science, Finance, etc. 
OPC on the other hand is general purpose cloud which could be just the VMs (IaaS) or Database/App Server/Fusion Middleware (PaaS) or an ERP product like HCM (SaaS).

OPC is self service - you just sign up for a service and you manage it entirely once you have access.

OCI is managed by Oracle.